# Generating RSA keys per the FIPS 186-4 standard

Tags: openssl, rsa, c, fips

my company is trying to get our OpenSSL 1.0.2l software (it's compiled in FIPS mode with the FIPS canister) FIPS certified, but I am having difficulty generating RSA keys according to the FIPS 186-4 testing format specified in (http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/dss2/rsa2vs.pdf).

I need to generate the following parameters using OpenSSL's API: `e`, `seed`, `p`, `q`, `n`, `d`. Where e is the public exponent, `p` and `q` are the prime numbers used for RSA key generation, `n` is simply `p*q`, and `d` is the private exponent, and `seed` is the value given to the PRNG to generate the prime numbers.

The problem is that I need to be able to access the `seed` value used in OpenSSL's RSA key generation just for FIPS testing purposes, but I have no clue where the `seed` value is stored/generated. I also might need to know how to set the `seed` value to an exact value. I am using the built in PRNG for openssl-fips.

Comment: According to their FIPS Security Policy (Section 4), OpenSSL's FIPS module doesn't support RSA key generation using 186-4. https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/SecurityPolicy-2.0.12.pdf

Comment: You're right, but still companies have gotten their OpenSSL RSA algorithms certified!!! Check out NIST's RSA validation list.

Comment: the only one using 1.0.2l isn't using key generation. The rest may have patched the code to use 186-4 key generation.

Comment: You are correct the other companies are using an open source patch from RedHat. I haven't looked into it yet.